# How to read error on setRequestHeader?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `xhr.setRequestHeader` to set up an authentication with `beforeSend` in jQuery. The code is like this:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(app.username + ':' + app.password));
}
```

Nothing fancy here, but let's say the password provided is incorrect, then my authentication fails… How to catch an error for that very part?

It seems that there is no callback function for `beforeSend` or `xhr.setRequestHeader`, anyone has a solution or wrote something to do this?

*Edit:*

This is the rest of the code

```
success: function(rows) {
    // everything is fine here when I provide correct username/password
},
error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.warn(responseData);
    console.warn(textStatus);
    console.warn(errorThrown);
    // nothing shows up in the console when I provide a bad username/password
}
```

*Edit 2:*

So, the thing is the XHR never fails because there was no controls server-side! Authentication successful or not, the call was made, and returned a `readyState` of 4 and a `status` of 200. If there is no error to display, it explains why I was unable to display it!

Comment: _How to catch an error for that very part?_ The same way as you deal with any error during AJAX request: `error` callback option. Or `fail` method of the jqXHR object. Nothing special.

Comment: jQuery has an error callback that you can hook into http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You can do it with the `error` callback function or the `.fail()` promise function. Check [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: _“It seems that there is no callback function for `beforeSend` or `xhr.setRequestHeader`”_ – even if there was, that wouldn’t help you here – because at that point it is not known that the credentials are not accepted by the server – only _after_ the request is send, that can be determined.

Comment: The thing is I tried with `error` and nothing is returned!

Comment: _The thing is I tried with error and nothing is returned!_ You have to provide details. Otherwise your question is offtopic.

Comment: Sorry @hindmost, I just finish editing my question/code

Comment: _nothing shows up in the console when I provide a bad username/password._ Try use `complete` callback instead of `error` and `console.log` instead of `console.warn`. BTW: The 1st argument of `error` is `jqXHR` object, not response data.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `xhr.setRequestHeader()` just adds some headers to a request.  It does not actually send it yet, so the password will not be validated until the request is actually sent by your other XHR code.  So, not failure will be seen at the time you set the header.

If the password is wrong, then the XHR response/status is where the error will be communicated back to you.  The XHR call will fail and (depending upon the server-side implementation), you will either get a status code that indicates the error or a specific response that indicates the error.

You can see the response with an `onreadystatechange` event handler.

If you need further help, then please add the rest of the code for sending and processing this ajax call to your question so we can advise more specifically.

Comment: @PierreLeBot - Open the network tag in the Chrome debugger while you issue one of these requests and then examine exactly what response you get over the network.  That will advise where to be looking for the error or why you aren't seeing it.  Also, if you are using basic auth, jQuery provides built-in options for passing the username and password.  See [`$.ajax()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for details.